# using python to find coefficient of polynomial

Tags: python, list, addition

I have the following two lists:

```
first = [1,2,3]
second = [6,7,8]
```

Now I want to add items of both lists into a new list.

output should be

```
three = [6, 7, 8, 12, 14, 16, 18, 21, 24]
```

Answer (score 2):

## list comprehension

You could use this list comprehension:

```
three = [i*j for i in first for j in second]
# [6, 7, 8, 12, 14, 16, 18, 21, 24]
```

## `itertools`

Alternatively, using `itertools.product` (though I'm not sure it will save you performance in this case):

```
from itertools import product

three = [i*j for i,j in product(first,second)]
# [6, 7, 8, 12, 14, 16, 18, 21, 24]
```

## `numpy`

Alternatively with `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

three = np.outer(first,second).flatten()
# array([ 6,  7,  8, 12, 14, 16, 18, 21, 24])
```